# What to do about an app with serious bugs that has already been submitted for release via managed publishing via Google Play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I directly pushed an app for release via managed publishing. Releasing it will cause chaos for our users as some endpoints are incorrect. How do I remove that build and replace it with a new one?

[App has been approved in managed publishing, worried that even if I push a separate build to prod track, this bad app will also get released](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsEJy.png)

Trying to delete the apk does not work as the delete buttons are missing. What can I do as the app really cannot go out in this state? Is there some way to remove the app?

Comment: "I directly pushed an app" What does it mean? You mean you published it with managed publishing or not yet?

Comment: Yes i pushed the app directly to prod without enough testing via managed publishing. The app has now been reviewed and ready for release in managed publishing.

Comment: Ok, so as I said, everything is fine. Just upload a new version and push it to the release track(where the bad version is).

Answer (score 1):

Just don't release it.

That's one of the advantages of `Managed publishing`. It's not released `released` until you confirm it in the Managed Publishing section.

The bad version is not released. Just upload a newer version with a fix and push it to the release track just as you did with this version.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I am very worried as in my previous experience there was only a single publish changes button. 

So if i promote a new version with an updated version code and the same existing version name, will only the good version get released?

Comment: Yes managed publishing is enabled.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help here @thelibrarian really appreciate it